# MySql - Get Column Names where Value is 1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, show

My MySql Table looks like this:

```
| id | picID      | name_Gina | name_Tom | name_Liz |
|----|------------|-----------|----------|----------|
| 1  | DSC057.jpg | 1         | 0        | 0        |
| 2  | DSC622.jpg | 1         | 0        | 1        |
| 3  | DSC624.jpg | 0         | 1        | 0        |
| .. | ..         | ..        | ..       | ..       |
```

and so on. The name_ Prefixes are my Persons that i associate with a certain pic. Now I would like to Display a Photo eg. DSC622.jpg and echo that Gina and Liz are marked on this Photo. So i need the Column Names (name_Gina & name_Liz) where picID = 1?

Sg like this:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table LIKE 'name_%' WHERE id = $id
```

Can anyone give me a hint?
Maybe I should use two Tables, one with Names and a second with the picID and join them together?

Comment: Aaaaaah. This DB design is just so wrong. Please change it. That is the only real solution to your problem!

Comment: Hey, Jurgen - i thougt so! Can you give me some tips how to design the tables and how to join them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really change your DB design to something like this

```
pictures table
--------------
id
name


users table
-----------
id
name
birth_date


user_pictures table
-------------------
picture_id
user_id
```

The `user_pictures` table would contain a record for every user-picture relation.

Example data

```
pictures
id   name
1    dsc_01.jpg
2    dsc_04.jpg

users
id  name
1   tom
2   jane

user_pictures
picture_id user_id
1          1
1          2
2          2
```

You can then select all pictures a specfic user is accociated with like this

```
select p.name
from pictures p
join user_pictures up on up.picture_id = p.id
join users u on up.user_id = u.id
where u.name = 'tom'
```

Comment: The third table with picture_id and user_id is generated on the fly by joining in php?

Comment: No. You create that table too in your MySQL DB.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner with mysql and I'll try your solution. Thank You!

Comment: After you understood that design you can add indexes to it to make it faster, more relyable and avoid duplicate data.

Comment: Could you give me the code how to generate the third table through sql-syntax ala' "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table_link`..." because i have to join this table in mysql?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50981/discussion-between-user2987790-and-juergen-d)